# DAX: date filter is not working

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I have simple measures, one for counting all client IDs who have a sign-in date no matter when, and another one, which should be counting all client IDs who signed-in this year:

```
Candidate = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('WSF - Hurtownia'[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE]);
    NOT(ISBLANK('WSF - Hurtownia'[Data zapisu]))
    )

Candidate CY = 
CALCULATE(
    [Candidate];
    DATESBETWEEN('WSF - Hurtownia'[Data zapisu];[Początek];[Koniec])
    )
```

The thing is that both give the same result and they should not.

Comment: I think there's an error in the two measures you use in the DATESBETWEEN. Could you post the definition of [Początek] and [Koniec]?

Comment: [Początek] and [Koniec] are measures which are pointing to a single day  either start/end of promo period or (if promo period is not selected) begining/end of measurement period:

`Początek = IFERROR(DATEVALUE([Promo start] & "-" & [Rok statystyki]);
                DATEVALUE("01-04-" & [Rok statystyki])) 

Koniec = IFERROR(DATEVALUE([Promo koniec] & "-" & [Rok statystyki]);
                DATEVALUE("30-11-" & [Rok statystyki])) `

[Rok statystyki] is just a year for which the measurement is done.